# Vuetify Treeview - moved items are not selectable when clicking on parent node

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm trying to move selected treeview items to another parent and it works except moved items are not selectable anymore when clicking on their new parent node.

Steps to reproduce:

- select `node2_item1`
- click the `Move to node1` button
- select `node1`

[image: actual behavior]

I'm using VueJS 2.6.14 & Vuetify 2.6.4

```html
    <template>
      <v-container>
        <v-row>
          <v-col>
            <v-treeview
              v-model="treeSelection"
              :items="tree"
              dense
              selectable
              return-object
              open-all
            >
            </v-treeview>
          </v-col>
          <v-col class="col-9">
            <v-btn class="mt-2" @click="moveSelectedItems('node1')">Move to node1</v-btn>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn class="mt-2" @click="moveSelectedItems('node2')">Move to node2</v-btn>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
    name: "TestTree",

    data() {
      return {
        treeSelection: [],
        items: {
          node1: ["node1_item1", "node1_item2", "node1_item3", "node1_item4"],
          node2: ["node2_item1", "node2_item2"]
        }
      };
    },

    computed: {
      tree() {
        let tree = [];

        for (const [node, items] of Object.entries(this.items)) {
          tree.push({
            id: node,
            name: node,
            children: items.map(n => ({
              id: n,
              name: n
            }))
          });
        }

        return tree;
      }
    },

    methods: {
      moveSelectedItems(nodeName) {
        if (this.treeSelection.length) {
          const selectedItems = this.treeSelection.map(el => el.id);
          let oldNodes = new Set();

          for (const itemId of selectedItems) {
            for (const [oldNodeName, items] of Object.entries(this.items)) {
              if (items.includes(itemId)) {
                oldNodes.add(oldNodeName);
              }
            }
          }

          const oldNodeName = [...oldNodes][0];

          for (const itemId of selectedItems) {
            for (const items of this.items[oldNodeName]) {
              if (items.includes(itemId)) {
                const oldNodeItemIndex = this.items[oldNodeName].findIndex(
                  el => el === itemId
                );

                if (oldNodeItemIndex !== -1) {
                  this.items[oldNodeName].splice(oldNodeItemIndex, 1);
                }
              }
            }

            this.items[nodeName].push(itemId);
          }

          this.treeSelection = [];
        }
      }
    }
    };
    </script>
```

**UPD** collapsing `node1` and expanding it back helps, but I'd like to refresh the tree programmatically somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of the solution will be to re-render treeview anyhow. So, i will suggest keep watch on treeSelection variable whenever its value changes increment the index
[here][1] is the live demo

```
watch: {
      treeSelection: {
        handler(n) {
           this.treeKey++;
        }
      }
       
     },
```

and in template section bind key attribute

```
<v-treeview
              v-model="treeSelection"
              :items="tree"
              dense
              selectable
              return-object
              open-all
              :key="treeKey"
            >
            </v-treeview>
```

[1]: https://codepen.io/nileshku123132522/pen/poVaBWN?editors=1010)